# Displaying Hex codes from buffer after reading from a file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm trying to store the hex codes read from a file into a buffer and then display it on the console, so far it doesn't seem to work. This is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 ifstream file("Fishie.ch8",ios::binary);
 if (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error";
}
else
{
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    streamoff size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    char *buffer = new char[size];
    file.read(buffer, size);
    file.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<hex<< buffer[i] << " ";
    }
}
delete[] buffer;
cin.get();
}
```

The expected output should be this:

```
00 e0 a2 20 62 08 60 f8 70 08 61 10 40 20 12 0e
d1 08 f2 1e 71 08 41 30 12 08 12 10 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 18 3c 3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3e 3f 3f 3b 39 38 38 38 00 00 80 c1 e7 ff 7e 3c
00 1f ff f9 c0 80 03 03 00 80 e0 f0 78 38 1c 1c
38 38 39 3b 3f 3f 3e 3c 78 fc fe cf 87 03 01 00
00 00 00 00 80 e3 ff 7f 1c 38 38 70 f0 e0 c0 00
3c 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Instead the above output I get some strange looking symbols with lots of empty spaces.
It looks like this:
[image: binary file output]
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you buffer is `char` all elements will be printed as characters. What you want is the number converted to hex.

BTW: As you want a conversion to hexadecimal output, it is a question if you really want to read `char` from file or `unsigned char`.

As you find out, the signature for `istream.read` uses `char` you have to convert before to `unsigned char` and than to `unsigned int` like:

```
cout <<hex<< (unsigned int)(unsigned char) buffer[i] << " ";
```

For real c++ users you should write a fine `static_cast` ;)

This will print out the hex values. But if you have a `CR` you will see a 'a' instead of '0a', so you have to set your width and fill char before:

```
cout.width(2);
cout.fill('0');

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{   
    cout <<hex<< (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[i] << " ";
}
```

BTW: `delete[] buffer;` is in wrong scope and must be shifted in the scope where it was defined.

Comment: You will need to `#include <iomanip>` for this to work.

Comment: @Sailanarmo: and <fstream> and <iostream>

Comment: @Klaus your solution works so far but there is a problem instead of `e0` I get `ffffffe0` and it happens to other values that are alphanumeric.

Comment: @Kulten: That is what I expect by conversion from `char` to `unsigned int`. So make your buffer `unsigned char` as already written in my answer ;) !

Comment: @Klaus thank for you taking the time to help me, when I change `char` to `unsigned char` I get an error at the line `file.read(buffer, size);` saying `note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`.

Comment: @Kulten: OK, than do a double conversion, see edit of my answer!

Comment: @Klaus was just about to comment that I fixed it by a double conversion lol, I did not see your prior comment or edit. Thank you so much.